# Multiple columns criteria to use with Vlookup in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I am  having issues with a formula that will look over columns and rows of data from one sheet to match the names with name on another sheet and pull a value to that sheet when it matches.  I have it working right now but I have a second column of data which may have a name it and may have a blank in it.  I need it to check that column and if it has a name in the second column it will put a 0 instead of the value associated with that row.

This the formula that almost works for me I am currently using: `=iferror(vlookup($A4,Match2!$B$6:$F,5,false),0)`

My sheet is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/130APwcPBOwQY-Q4xt-Q46_S_-sDXy7NploNX6DkObQw/edit?usp=sharing

I need the scores from the Match sheets from column F to come over to the Handicaps sheet based on matching the names in Column A on Handicaps with Column B names in the Match sheets but I also need to look at Column C on the Match sheets to see if a name is there or a blank. If a name is in Col C put a 0 not the score in Col F from the Match sheets.

I hope I explained this so everyone can understand. Thank you for your help ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It checks the length of column C and if it is less than 2 it does what your formula else 0.

```
=if(len(vlookup($A4,Match1!$B$6:$F,2,false))<2,vlookup($A4,Match1!$B$6:$F,5,false),0)
```

If you also want to check for S or F use:

```
=if(len(vlookup($A4,Match1!$B$6:$F,2,false))<1,vlookup($A4,Match1!$B$6:$F,5,false),if(vlookup($A4,Match1!$B$6:$F,2,false)="S","S",if(vlookup($A4,Match1!$B$6:$F,2,false)="F","F",0)))
```

Comment: I am so sorry I think this is setup backwards for what I am wanting. I need Tab named Handicaps to do the vlookup against the name in it's Column A with the Match tabs per week and if the Match tab/sheet has a name or F in its Column C then do not get that score from that Match tab. I am going to try to see if I can reverse yours to work the way I need Ed and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ed I am sorry it was my silliness but I got it to work by using your formulas. Again thank you so much.